# How can I retrict the text inside a block in html?

Tags: html

I have the following html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>123456</span>
        <span>ABC DEF HGI KLM NOP QRS TUV WXYZ ASASASASASAS </span>            
    </div>
</body>
```

Problem: When the browers becomes smaller the alphanumeric text wraps under 123456.
I want it to wrap inside the span an not under the left span.
I.e.

```
123456 ABC DEF HGI KLM NOP QRS 
       TUV WXYZ ASASASASASASASAS
```

and not

```
123456 ABC DEF HGI KLM NOP QRS 
TUV WXYZ ASASASASASASASAS
```

Is there a way to do that without using css? Only inline properties?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, set the display property for the spans to table-cell:

```css
span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>123456</span>
  <span>ABC DEF HGI KLM NOP QRS TUV WXYZ ASASASASASAS </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: But in the OP I asked for something that does not involve CSS

Comment: The only way to do it without CSS is to use actual tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try floats:

```css
span:first-child {
  float: left;
}
span:last-child {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>123456</span>
  <span>ABC DEF HGI KLM NOP QRS TUV WXYZ ASASASASASAS</span>
</div>
```

Comment: But in the OP I asked for something that does not involve CSS

Comment: That makes no sense. HTML and JS are not presentational by themselves.